# SQL Server - select a commonly named column over multiple joined tables where the last edit date is most recent

Tags: sql-server

Our County recently purchased a new real-estate system. I have created a view that joins over a dozen tables. (assessment, taxpayer, collections, etc...)

Every table has a last change data and last change user field.

We would like to know when a parcel number was last changed in the system and what login made those changes.

I was able to pull the most recent change data by using the following nested query...

```
SELECT 
    ... ,
    (SELECT MAX(v) 
     FROM (VALUES (table1.last_chg_datetime), (table2.last_chg_datetime), 
                  (table3.last_chg_datetime), (table4.last_chg_datetime), ... , 
                  (tableN.last_chg_datetime)) AS value(v)) AS last_chg_datetime 
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ...
```

What is the best way to also pull the last changed user from the table that corresponds with the last changed date?

I am sure this could be done with a stored procedure. I was just wondering if this could also be extracted by altering the nested query?

We are running SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT  ... ,sub. *
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ...
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
     FROM (VALUES (table1.last_chg_datetime, table1.user), (table2.last_chg_datetime, table2.user), 
                  (table3.last_chg_datetime, table3.user), (table4.last_chg_datetime, table4.user), ... , 
                  (tableN.last_chg_datetime, tableN.user)) AS value(v, user_name)
    ORDER BY v DESC
   ) sub;
```

It could be also extended by table  name:

```
(VALUES ('table1', table1.last_chg_datetime, table1.user), 
        ('table2', table2.last_chg_datetime, table2.user), ...
) AS value(table_name, v, user_name)
```

Comment: @kcrombez OUTER APPLY works like a correlated subquery per each row. Please note that I am refering to any table defined in FROM/JOIN clause so if parcel_num is  part of any table you don't have to join it

Comment: @kcrombez Glad to hear I could help :)